# Python Bubble Sort, 10 being considered < 5, 7 etc

Tags: python

I have created a bubble sort program in which the user is able to enter the values which will be stored in the array which will be sorted by the bubble sort algorithm, however the output is not what I expect if i enter the values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10 will be sorted to just after 1 changing the sorted list to 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 which makes me believe that 10 is being read as 1 instead of 10 but I have no idea why.

```
    def initlist():
    unsortedlist=[]

    for counter in range (0,10):
        print("Please enter value", (counter+1))
        temp = input("")
        unsortedlist.append(temp)
    return unsortedlist


def BubbleSort(unsortedlist):
    passes = 0
    print ("Fixed Loop")
    print ("Initial State:", unsortedlist)

    passes = 0
    swaps = 0
    for outer in range(len(unsortedlist) -1, 0, -1):
        passes += 1
        for inner in range (outer):
            if unsortedlist[inner] > unsortedlist[inner + 1]:
                swaps +=1
                temp = unsortedlist[inner]
                unsortedlist[inner] = unsortedlist[inner+1]
                unsortedlist[inner + 1] = temp

            print("Pass", passes, ":", unsortedlist)
    input("Press Any Key To Continue")
```

**Output**

```
Pass 1 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 1 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 1 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 2 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 2 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 2 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 2 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 2 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 2 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 2 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 2 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 3 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 3 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 3 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 3 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 3 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 3 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 3 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 4 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 4 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 4 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 4 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 4 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 4 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 5 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 5 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 5 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 5 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 5 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 6 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 6 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 6 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 6 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 7 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 7 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 7 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 8 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 8 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
Pass 9 : ['1', '10', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: You appear to be sorting *strings*?! Which would naturally lead to `'10'` being < `'2'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp = input("")` reads input as strings. you are doing a lexicographical sorting here.

If you want to sort integers, then change to `temp = int(input(""))`